# How to access filters from filterpanel when tablegroups are empty

Tags: spotfire

When I try to access the filters in my filterpanel by first retrieving TableGroups[0], I get the error message that ValueError: Value of argument 'index' is 0, which is out of the allowed range [0 - -1].

This kind of makes sense since I do not have filter groups. But then how can I access my filters?

Here is my full code:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import ScatterPlot, TablePlot, BarChart
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Layout import LayoutDefinition
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import ListBoxFilter, FilterPanel

for Page in Document.Pages:
  if Page.Title != "Selection":
    Document.Pages.Remove(Page)


page = Document.Pages.AddNew("QC alert")
page.HasMinimumHeight = True
page.MinimumHeight = 1600
demandcompounds = Document.Properties['compoundbox']

cmpndcounter = 0
for compound in range(len(demandcompounds)):
    Application.Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals.AddNew[ScatterPlot]()
    Application.Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals.AddNew[TablePlot]()

layout = LayoutDefinition()
visuals = list(page.Visuals)
layout.BeginStackedSection()

counter = 0
for visual in range(len(visuals)):
    if counter % 2 == 0 and counter != 0:
        layout.EndSection()
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        layout.BeginSideBySideSection()
    layout.Add(visuals[counter])
    counter += 1

layout.EndSection()
layout.EndSection()
page.ApplyLayout(layout)


for visual in visuals:

    vis = visual.As[VisualContent]()
    if type(vis) == TablePlot :
        data = Document.Data.Tables["abcddata"]
        vis.Data.DataTableReference = data
        vis.TableColumns.Add(data.Columns.Item["JNJ_BATCH_ID"])
    counter += 1

filterPanel = Application.Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel
filterGroup= filterPanel.TableGroups[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The API and logical organization for filters is quite complex.
Maybe you can provide more context to what you wish to do, and the script you are currently trying.
When you first open your analysis, you have one default filtering scheme (called Filtering Scheme) with all the data tables in your analysis.
This is associated with the FilterPanel on each page.
Your TableGroups[0] should reference the first table in the scheme, i.e. what they call the 'root' group. (I don't understand how the value 0 could be outside the range 0-1).
Below an example on how to get to the filters for the first table:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *

filterPanel = page.FilterPanel

#Get the first table
filterGroup= filterPanel.TableGroups[0]
print (filterGroup.Name)
handles = filterGroup.FilterHandles
for hh in handles:
    print (hh.FilterReference)
```

At this point, hh.FilterReference contains an object of type Filter for all the column filters in the first data table.

Comment: I figured out that my TableGroups[] is empty when I try to get it from the page that I newly created in the same script. When I move the bottom lines of code to the lines before page = Document.Pages.AddNew("QC alert"), TableGroups[] is not null.

Perhaps it is not possible to do this in one script? Do you happen to know of a workaround if so?

Comment: It looks like your script does a lot of extra things on top of accessing filters. Not having the full context, I don't understand the implications of creating a page within the same script that is trying to access its filters. I recommend providing a small example that is representative of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Got it now: when you create a new page, no filtering scheme is selected yet by default. When I set my filterPanel.FilteringSchemeReference to the default one, my TableGroups is no longer empty.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you create a new page, no filtering scheme is selected yet by default. When I set my filterPanel.FilteringSchemeReference to the default one, my TableGroups is no longer empty.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).